# BeautifulSoup: Scraping answers from form

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the answers to the questions from the following [link](https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0), including the check boxes.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = 'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

The following gives me all the written answers, if there are any:

```
soup.find_all('span', {'class':'PrintHistRed'})
```

and I think I can piece together all the checkbox answers from this:

```
soup.find_all('img')
```

but these aren't going to be ordered correctly, because this doesn't pick up the "No Information Filed" answers that aren't written in red.

I also feel like there's a much better way to be doing this. Ideally I want (for the first 6 questions) to return:

```
['APEX INVESTMENT FUND, V, L.P',
 '805-2054766781',
 'Delaware',
 'United States',
 'APEX MANAGEMENT V, LLC',
 'X',
 'O',
 'No Information Filed',
 'NO',
 'NO']
```

**EDIT**

Martin's answer below seems to do the trick, however when I put it in a loop, the results begin to change after the 3rd iteration. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

for x in range(5):
    url = 'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0'
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

    tags = list(soup.find_all('span', {'class':'PrintHistRed'}))
    tags.extend(list(soup.find_all('img', alt=re.compile('Radio|Checkbox')))[2:])       # 2: skip "are you an adviser" at the top
    tags.extend([t.parent for t in soup.find_all(text="No Information Filed")])

    output = []

    for entry in sorted(tags):
        if entry.name == 'img':
            alt = entry['alt']
            if 'Radio' in alt:
                output.append('NO' if 'not selected' in alt else 'YES')
            else:
                output.append('O' if 'not checked' in alt else 'X')
        else:
            output.append(entry.text)

    print output[:9]
```

Answer (score 1):

The website does not generate any of the required HTML via Javascript, so I have chosen to use just `requests` to get the HTML (which should be faster).

One approach to solving your problem is to store all the tags for your three different types into a single array. If this is then sorted, it will result in the tags being in tree order.

The first search simply uses your `PrintHistRed` to get the matching span tags. Secondly it finds all `img` tags that have `alt` text containing either the word `Radio` or `Checkbox`. Lastly it searches for all locations where `No Information Filed` is found and returns the parent tag.

The tags can now be sorted and a suitable `output` array built containing the information in the required format:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0'
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

tags = list(soup.find_all('span', {'class':'PrintHistRed'}))
tags.extend(list(soup.find_all('img', alt=re.compile('Radio|Checkbox')))[2:])       # 2: skip "are you an adviser" at the top
tags.extend([t.parent for t in soup.find_all(text="No Information Filed")])

output = []

for entry in sorted(tags):
    if entry.name == 'img':
        alt = entry['alt']
        if 'Radio' in alt:
            output.append('NO' if 'not selected' in alt else 'YES')
        else:
            output.append('O' if 'not checked' in alt else 'X')
    else:
        output.append(entry.text)

print output[:9]        # Display the first 9 entries
```

Giving you:

```
[u'APEX INVESTMENT FUND V, L.P.', u'805-2054766781', u'Delaware', u'United States', 'X', 'O', u'No Information Filed', 'NO', 'YES']
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really great. I'm getting the error: "TypeError: unorderable types: Tag() < Tag()". I'm using Python 3, not Python 2. Do you think this could be the reason?

Comment: I was able to get the script to run in Python 2, but any idea how to get it run in Python 3?

Comment: I've just recreated your error, and It would appear that `Tag()` comparison has not been implemented in the Python 3 version. I would suggest you raise a ticket on the beautifulsoup site to see if there is a workaround or if it a known issue.

Comment: Hey Martin, when I put this in a loop (I have to loop through a number of different URLs), it starts giving me incorrect results after the 4th iteration. Even when I use that same URL as above. Any idea why this is?

Comment: to replicate, all I did was put the whole thing in a for x in range(5): loop, and after the 3rd iteration the results start to change.

Comment: My guess is that it isn't really designed to sort tags like this. I have raised a question on the forum and am waiting for a reply.

Comment: Thanks, but even in Python 2.x? The code works fine when you run it once, however the results just change after the 3rd time you run it in a row

Comment: I put the example loop in the original question if you wanted to take a look, thanks again

Comment: I have tested it with a very simple example and it failed to sort correctly on Python 2.x on the first try.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to amend the code to spit out what I need in the order I need it, however it's failing when I try to implement it in a loop

Answer (score 0):

I've looked fairly carefully at the HTML. I doubt there is an utterly simple way of scraping pages like this.

I would begin with an analysis, looking for similar questions. For instance, 11 through 16 inclusive can likely be handled in the same way.  19 and 21 appear to be similar. There may or may not be others.

I would work out how to handle each type of similar question as given by the rows containing them. For example, how would I handle 19 and 21? Then I would write code to identify the rows for the questions noting the question number for each. Finally I would use the appropriate code using the row number to winkle out information from it. In other words, when I encountered question 19 I'd use the code meant for either 19 or 21.