# BeautifulSoup: output starts to change after certain number of iterations in loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I got an answer to a question I asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532846/beautifulsoup-scrapping-answers-from-form) that seems to work when I run the code once.

However, when I try to implement it in a loop, the results start to change after the 3rd iteration. This is just an example that calls the same URL each time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

for x in range(5):
    url = 'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0'
    html = requests.get(url, headers={'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=notimportant'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

    tags = list(soup.find_all('span', {'class':'PrintHistRed'}))
    tags.extend(list(soup.find_all('img', alt=re.compile('Radio|Checkbox')))[2:])       # 2: skip "are you an adviser" at the top
    tags.extend([t.parent for t in soup.find_all(text="No Information Filed")])

    output = []

    for entry in sorted(tags):
        if entry.name == 'img':
            alt = entry['alt']
            if 'Radio' in alt:
                output.append('NO' if 'not selected' in alt else 'YES')
            else:
                output.append('O' if 'not checked' in alt else 'X')
        else:
            output.append(entry.text)

    print output[:9]
```

I've tried putting in a time.sleep() in various places in the code, thinking it had to do with that, but no luck. I'm also wondering if has something to do with cookies? But have no idea, really...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you put the imports inside of the loop?

Comment: That actually makes the output start changing after the 2nd iteration, funnily. Not sure if that provides anyone with any clues...

Comment: Well that's weird.

Comment: They may be using javascript

Comment: What if you get rid of the loop and copy and paste the code five times?

Comment: Does this happen if you run the code 5 times (without a loop)

Comment: is it ok that your `print` statement is inside of loop over sorted tags?

Comment: Yeah, it does. And I do think the site uses Javascript

Comment: It may be tracking requests from your ip

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate the problem. I'm really trying to save the output list for ~ 3000 different URLs and combine them into a DataFrame. And you would think that they would just block my IP as opposed to changing the results I get, if that's the case. It seems that the order of the results is just changing.

Comment: You may want to look into dryscrape, as it can run javascript https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dryscrape/1.0

Comment: Or selenium webdriver, though it is slow if you want to do 3000 urls

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting "objects" (of type bs4.element.Tag, see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) and not strings in you code so you are getting weird behaviour.

Change:

```
for entry in sorted(tags):
```

to:

```
for entry in tags:
```

Then it outputs:

```
[u'APEX INVESTMENT FUND V, L.P.', u'805-2054766781', u'Delaware', u'United States', u'$\xa07,402,178', u'$\xa05,000,000', u'47', u'4', u'28']
[u'APEX INVESTMENT FUND V, L.P.', u'805-2054766781', u'Delaware', u'United States', u'$\xa07,402,178', u'$\xa05,000,000', u'47', u'4', u'28']
[u'APEX INVESTMENT FUND V, L.P.', u'805-2054766781', u'Delaware', u'United States', u'$\xa07,402,178', u'$\xa05,000,000', u'47', u'4', u'28']
[u'APEX INVESTMENT FUND V, L.P.', u'805-2054766781', u'Delaware', u'United States', u'$\xa07,402,178', u'$\xa05,000,000', u'47', u'4', u'28']
[u'APEX INVESTMENT FUND V, L.P.', u'805-2054766781', u'Delaware', u'United States', u'$\xa07,402,178', u'$\xa05,000,000', u'47', u'4', u'28']
```

Updated in response to comment, if you need to preserve the order try something like this (you could condense the code more if you like, there is no need for two for statements):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

for x in range(5):
    url = 'https://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/content/viewform/adv/Sections/iapd_AdvPrivateFundReportingSection.aspx?ORG_PK=161227&FLNG_PK=05C43A1A0008018C026407B10062D49D056C8CC0'
    html = requests.get(url, headers={'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=notimportant'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

    regexp = re.compile(r'Radio|Checkbox')
    mytags = []
    tags = soup.find_all(['span', 'img'])
    for tag in tags:
        if (tag.has_attr('class') and 'PrintHistRed' in tag['class']) or (tag.has_attr('alt') and regexp.search(tag['alt']) ):
            mytags.append(tag)
        elif (tag.text == "No Information Filed"):
            mytags.append(tag.parent)

    output = []

    for entry in mytags:
        if entry.name == 'img':
            alt = entry['alt']
            if 'Radio' in alt:
                output.append('NO' if 'not selected' in alt else 'YES')
            else:
                output.append('O' if 'not checked' in alt else 'X')
        else:
            output.append(entry.text)

    print (output)
```

Comment: I need outputs to be sorted according to how they appear on the site. This won't give me the output in the correct order, which is what sorted(tags) does (sometimes). I should extend the example output so you see what I mean.